# Excel with c#: Exculde first rows when copying a range

Tags: c#, .net, excel

The following command copied the complete used range into the clipboard:

```
                mySheet.UsedRange.Copy();
```

I want to just exculde the first row and copy the rest into clip board. Please help

Comment: which library do you use?

Comment: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try to get it with something like this:

```
Excel.Range dataWithoutFirstRow = mySheet.Range[mySheet.UsedRange.Cells[2, 1],
      mySheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell)];
```

Comment: Range dataWithoutFirstRow = currentWorkSheet.Range[currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Cells[2, 1], currentWorkSheet.Cells[currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, currentWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count]]; this works for me