# C# Excel Interop - remove first row from Range

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I'm trying to remove the first row of a given range. But getting a Type Mismatch error.

From this examples:
[Excel with c#: Exculde first rows when copying a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590659/excel-with-c-exculde-first-rows-when-copying-a-range)

I'm trying something like this:

```
Excel.Range rngNoHeaders = NamedRange.RefersToRange[NamedRange.RefersToRange.Cells[2, 1], NamedRange.RefersToRange.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell)];
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Given any range (the example below I just picked one arbitrarily), this is how you would delete the first row of that range:

```
Excel.Range r = ws.Range["A18:A23"];
r.Rows[1].EntireRow.Delete();
```

So I assumed `NamedRange` is a object of type Range?  If so:

```
NamedRange.Rows[1].EntireRow.Delete();
```